# How can I copy documents from one collection to the other only once Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get specific data from a subcollection in Firebase and copy it only once (so no stream) to another collection. How can I fix the code to make this work? Probably I need to change something with the getDocuments() but I don't know how to make this work. Thanks for your help.

```
  void copy() async {
 await  _firestore
    .collection('users')
    .document(loggedinUser.uid)
    .collection('Dates')
    .document(yesterdayDate)
    .collection(widget.reference)
    .getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {snapshot.documents.forEach((message) {

      final getitem = message.data['item'];
    final getarchieved = message.data['archived'];
    final getchecked = message.data['checked'];}) {




    if (getchecked == false && widget.reference == 'Todo') {
      _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .document(loggedinUser.uid)
          .collection('Dates')
          .document(selectedDate)
          .collection(widget.reference)
          .add({
        'item': getitem,
        'archived': getarchieved,
        'checked': getchecked
      });
    } else if (widget.reference == 'Goals') {
      _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .document(loggedinUser.uid)
          .collection('Dates')
          .document(selectedDate)
          .collection(widget.reference)
          .add({
        'item': getitem,
        'archived': getarchieved,
        'checked': false
      });
    }



  }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of research and trial and error I finally have a solution that works. I hope I can help someone facing the same issue with this solution:

```
void copy() async {
QuerySnapshot snaphsot = await _firestore
    .collection('users')
    .document(loggedinUser.uid)
    .collection('Dates')
    .document(yesterdayDate)
    .collection(widget.reference)
    .getDocuments();

for (var message in snaphsot.documents) {
  final getitem = message.data['item'];
  final getarchieved = message.data['archived'];
  final getchecked = message.data['checked'];

  if (getchecked == false && widget.reference == 'Todo') {
    _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .document(loggedinUser.uid)
        .collection('Dates')
        .document(selectedDate)
        .collection(widget.reference)
        .add({
      'item': getitem,
      'archived': getarchieved,
      'checked': getchecked
    });
  } else if (widget.reference == 'Goals') {
    _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .document(loggedinUser.uid)
        .collection('Dates')
        .document(selectedDate)
        .collection(widget.reference)
        .add({'item': getitem, 'archived': getarchieved, 'checked': false});
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution is great it helped me fix my problem. In my case I wanted a function which allows me to move a document from a collection into another collection.

But I also wanted to delete the old document after copying it into a new collection and didnt want to iterate threw documents. I later on faced a situation, where there was no document with the provided id to get copied, so I had to throw an error for this.

Thats why I decided to post my function here too, so people can choose the relevant parts from Felix and my function containing copy, delete, detect, and error handling for no available document.

```
moveDocumentToOtherCollection(String docId) async {

    var oldColl = db.collection('oldcollection').doc(docId);
    var newColl = db.collection('newcollection').doc(oldColl.id);


    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await oldColl.get()
    // ignore: missing_return
    .then((docSnapshot) {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {

    // document id does exist
    print('Successfully found document');

    newColl
      .set({
        'name': docSnapshot['name'],
        'message': docSnapshot['message'],
        'id': docSnapshot['id'],
        'isnew': docSnapshot['isnew'],
        'dateWhenProofed': DateTime.now(),
        'approved': true
        
      })
      .then((value) => print("document moved to different collection"))
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to move document: $error")).then((value) => ({

    oldColl
      .delete()
      .then((value) => print("document removed from old collection"))
      .catchError((error) {

        newColl.delete();
        print("Failed to delete document: $error");

      })
      }));

    } else {

      //document id doesnt exist
      print('Failed to find document id');
    }
    });
  }
```